# The meaning of aspectual "come"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've noticed that in English the verb "come" at times seems to have a function of an aspect of the verb that follows it, but I am not sure.

"but later he **came to fund** the effort from his own coffers"

What is the difference here from:

"but later he **funded** the effort from his own coffers"

?

Or:

"Although their output **has come to include** vault items and remixed mash-ups, the Beatles' "core catalogue", recorded between 1962 and 1970, comprises 213 songs."

What's the difference here from:

"Although their output **includes** vault items and remixed mash-ups..."

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Come to" is often used to refer to an 'arrival' at a thought or situation, not just a literal journey to a physical place.

For example:

- I came to the conclusion that / I concluded that
- I came to realise that / I realised that

These are both ways of showing that the end was the result of some figurative 'journey' or thought process and not just a random, passing thought that popped into your head.

In your first example, it is a good way of showing that he didn't fund the effort from the very beginning, but *came to* that situation as a result of whatever events led up to it.

In your second example about The Beatles, it is speaking about output which came later much later being accepted as part of their body of work. When the Beatles were active, they put out recordings and that was considered as their body of work. Since then, other recordings have been put out, some of which were originally rejected and remained "in the vault". So there has been a *progression* from a situation where only their original output was considered their work, to one where the material released later has also been accepted.

Comment: Thanks, but what kind of "arrival" is there in the second example?

Comment: @brilliant It wouldn't be unusual to say "I arrived at the conclusion". A realisation could come after a series of experiences. In your example, a series of failed funding attempts could have forced him to self-fund.

Comment: I was asking about the second example, that is, about the Beatles.

Comment: @brilliant ok i've added that into the answer.